# Unable to import pyd while extending CPython on windows

Tags: python, c, windows, python-2.7, cpython

i've been programming python for quite a bit now, and decided that i want to get to know the language better, i wanted to extend python, using CPython.

i found some cool ideas and now want to implement them.
i read the documentations about extending cpython, and on windows in praticular here:
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html#building-on-windows

I use CLion, with cygwin 64bit to program from my windows computer.
i first decided i want to compile and import the example from python's doc, so my C module looks like that:

```
#include <Python.h>
static PyObject *SpamError;

static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    if (sts < 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(SpamError, "System command failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
        {"system", spam_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command."},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    m = Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
    if (m==NULL)
        return;
    SpamError = PyErr_NewException("spam.error", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(SpamError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "error", SpamError);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    initspam();
}
```

my cmake.txt is the following one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(spam)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES spammodule.c)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
message(STATUS INCLUDE DIRS = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(spam SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(spam ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

i manage to combile the code and get my dll file,
but when i change the file suffix to pyd and import i encounter the following exception:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

while the traceback contains only frame in which the command ran is:

```
import spam
```

which is understandable, since that is the only command i run on the python's side, and the rest occurs in the C code.

I Run windows 10, 64bit, (my python and cygwin are 64bit aswell), and using cygwin to simulate linux, so i could develop on my CLion IDE.

Does anybody have any idea why that might happen? (and how to fix it)
it would be greatly appreciated!

p.s:

i have tried to build the extension with distutils using this setup.py:

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

```
spam_module = Extension(name='spam', sources=['spammodule.c'], include_dirs=['D:/cygwin/usr/include/python2.7',
                                                                             'D:/cygwin/usr/include'],
                        libraries=['D:/cygwin/lib/libpython2.7.dll.a'])

setup(name='spam',
      version='1.0',
      description='Default Package',
      ext_modules=[spam_module])
```

but i get an exception while running as following:

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'spam' extension
D:\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe     /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -ID:/cygwin/usr/include/python2.7 -     ID:/cygwin/usr/include -ID:\Python27\include -ID:\Python27\PC /Tcspammodule.c      /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\spammodule.obj
spammodule.c
D:/cygwin/usr/include\sys/_types.h(94) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow     '__extension__'
D:/cygwin/usr/include\sys/_types.h(94) : error C2085: '_off64_t' : not in     formal parameter list
D:/cygwin/usr/include\sys/_types.h(100) : error C2085: '__off_t' : not in     formal parameter list
D:/cygwin/usr/include\sys/_types.h(103) : error C2085: '_off64_t' : not in     formal parameter list
error: command 'D:\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for     Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Im desperate, trying to find a solution for few days, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The officially supported build setup is [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266), which requires using `setuptools` instead of `distutils`.

Comment: im pretty sure that distutils uses vcrasal.bat or something near that name, which is a part of the VCPython2.7, if you watch my exception, you can see it was used

Comment: AFAIK, distutils was never modified to work with it. Please try `setuptools`. Also, MSVC should never be including Cygwin headers; that makes no sense. You need to fix your setup.py to get rid of the `include_dirs` and `libraries` settings that you've configured for building on Cygwin.

Comment: if i don't set the include files manually, the setup.py doesn't find my header files, could you please tell me what is the default location for included directories? (the equivalent of /usr/include)

Comment: distutils/setuptools doesn't need help to find Python's header files. It included `D:\Python27\include` for you, and it will link with python27.lib for you when it gets to the link stage.

Comment: setuptools did work, thank you so much, you helped me alot!